# How to get touch screen coordination from WM_INPUT raw data

Tags: c++, winapi, touch, touchscreen, raw-input

I have my touch screen monitor registered with RegisterRawInputDevices. When I tap with one finger, I receive many WM_INPUT event.

How can I get readable data from WM_INPUT HID (touch) event (coordinations, type of touch)?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
case WM_INPUT:
do
        {
            // determine the size of the input data
            UINT data_size(0);
            GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, NULL,
                &data_size, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
            // preallocate our buffer
            vector<BYTE> data;
            data.resize(data_size);
            // and then read the input data in
            if (GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, &data[0],
                &data_size, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)) != data_size)
            {
                // handle the error gracefully
                mylog("ERROR");
                break;
            }
            // the RAWINPUT structure starts at the beginning of our data array
            RAWINPUT* raw = (RAWINPUT*)(&data[0]);
            // make sure keyboard/mouse HID data didn't somehow sneak its way in here
            if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEHID)
            {
                // for each packet received..
                for (DWORD index(0); index < raw->data.hid.dwCount; ++index)
                {
                    mylog(".............HID packet .............");
                    // reinterpret the data as our nicely formatted digitizer-specific structure
                    DigitizerData* result((DigitizerData*)&raw->data.hid.bRawData[raw->data.hid.dwSizeHid * index]);
                    // for each touch registered...
                    for (BYTE touch_index(0); touch_index < result->active_touch_count; ++touch_index)
                    {
                        // insert touch handler code here
                        int touch_x(result->touch[touch_index].X());
                        int touch_y(result->touch[touch_index].Y());

                        mylog(string("Touch point ") + std::to_string(touch_x) + string(" x ") + std::to_string(touch_y));

                    }
                }
            }
        } while (0);
return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    break;
}
```

Digitizer data and code is from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/381673/Using-the-RawInput-API-to-Process-MultiTouch-Digit .

Output of this code when one finger tap:

[image]

Comment: Can you use WM_TOUCH instead?

Comment: Problem is WM_TOUCH is called only when app is in foreground (active). If WS_EX_TRANSPARENT is used for cpp windows, no WM_TOUCH is called (only WM_INPUT). I need to inspect touch points when using another app. I want to know if touch points are badly reported in my Java app or my touch screen is broken, so I'm building this cpp "touch-logger".

Comment: I can get PHIDP_PREPARSED_DATA with GetRawInputDeviceInfo-RIDI_PREPARSEDDATA, but don't know how to interpret it.

Comment: That is the thing about using the Raw Input API, you get RAW data that is specific to the device that is sending it. Are you sure the `DigitizerData` code you are using is even appropriate for your particular touch screen? The code presented in that CodeProject article is SAMPLE code, it even say not to use it as-is for all devices. You are going to have to figure out what your particular device is actually sending, and then code for it. Contact the manufacturer, or maybe look at Linux's source code for its touch screen drivers, like the article suggests.